# How find nested div with same class name in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to find all div with specific class name. May be one div have nested div with parent div class name. suppose this example:

```
<div class="myForm">
   <div class ="myDiv">
     <div class ="myDiv">
     </div> 
   </div> 
   <div class ="myDiv">
     <div class ="myDiv">
     </div> 
   </div> 
</div>
```

In fact I want to find all div with "myDiv" class name and also recognize nested div. In the above example, there are 2 to 4 of them are nesting.

Comment: Use _$('.myDiv')_ selector. Eg:  _$('.myDiv').remove()_ That will remove all divs with _myDiv_ class.

Comment: If myDiv will be the only children of parent myDiv then having that class name for the children is redundant. You can query the children from the parent element using myDiv class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`>`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors), direct children selector

```
$('.myForm > .myDiv')
```

or

```
$('.myDiv').parent('.mydiv')
```

or

```
$('.myForm').children('.myDiv')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

For all `myDiv's`:

```
$('.myDiv')
```

For All nested `myDiv's` only:

```
$('.myDiv .myDiv')
```

For Only main 'myDiv's' excluding nested myDiv's:

```
$(".myDiv").not(".myDiv .myDiv")
```

Check Out this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f0gL4w24/)**

Comment: Why Downvote, Please Comment and let me know the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var element = $(".myForm").find(".myDiv");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think an answer would also mention that having redundant class names for children is bad practice and should be avoided.

```
<div class="myForm">
   <div class ="myDiv">
     <div>
     </div> 
   </div> 
   <div class ="myDiv">
     <div>
     </div> 
   </div> 
</div>
```

Query children like, `$('.myDiv, .myDiv > div')` or make separate class names for nested divs.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the **>** operator in element selector like

```js
$('.myForm > .myDiv').child('.myDiv');
```